# Register controller in all apps that use an assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is this possible to achieve?

I want to make a library (lets call it Foolib) that will automatically add an mvc controller with a fix route to all mvc applications that have a dependency on Foolib.

Foolib is to be used in several intranet applications that we are developing and I want to make sure that all applications that use of Foolib have an standard ability to receive a configuration object.

In Foolib there will be a controller something like:

```
public FooController 
{
    [Route("/Foo")]
    public Post(object obj)
    {
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to register the controller automatically to all web applications that uses Foolib?

Normally the calls to register controllers are made in the Startup class, how would I hook in this extra controller, hopefully without having to burden the other mvc application developers with an "just add this line to your startup" solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts)

"By default MVC will search the dependency tree and find controllers (even in other assemblies)."

So it should just work.

Comment: But I guess any application using Foolib will have to add this `var assembly = typeof(FooController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
services.AddMvc()
    .AddApplicationPart(assembly);` ? I don't think that *all* assemblies are scanned for controllers?